# Правильно ли проставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Рассмотрев ваше обращение, сообщаем, в ООО «Рога и копыта» отсутствует потребность в приобретении мотоцикла в 2021 году.

Если да или нет, то скажите, на какое правило русского языка ссылаетесь. Спасибо.

Comment: Во-первых, ваш приказной тон здесь неуместен. Во-вторых, извольте объяснить, что именно вызвало у вас затруднения, а не формулировать домашние задания для проверки наших знаний.

Comment: Здравствуйте, не хотел никому приказывать, извиняюсь кого оскорбил этим. Смысл заключается в написании мною письма, секретарь меня поправил убрав запятую после слова «обращение». Мои затруднения заключаются в том, что я поверхностно знаю правила русского языка, я специалист в другой области. Но меня задел тот факт, что человек поправляя меня, не знает правила и без обоснования причины убирает запятую. Поэтому обратился сюда за помощью. С уважением Ганеж.

Comment: дело не в какой-то обиде (её не было), а в том, что вы нарушили сложившийся "формат" общения на ресурсе. Здесь так не принято. Нужно обозначить проблему, с решением которой всегда будут готовы помочью А не ждать, что вам бесплатно выполнят редактирование/проверку. Ладно, вопрос исчерпан.

Comment: Я не увидел определённый формат, т.к. найдя этот ресурс в гугле, я сразу начал писать о проблеме и не ознакомился с правилами форума. Я повторюсь, если вас задели мои слова извините. На счёт платно/бесплатно, то дайте мне развёрнутый ответ, и если вам нужны за это деньги, давайте номер карты, я заплачу за ваш труд.

Comment: Это уже не имеет значения. Именно про формат вам и сообщили.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны **два варианта оформления:**

(1) *Рассмотрев ваше обращение, сообщаем: в ООО «Рога и копыта» отсутствует потребность в приобретении мотоцикла в 2021 году.*  Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП) с изъяснительным значением, ставится **двоеточие**, а не запятая.

(2) *Рассмотрев ваше обращение, сообщаем, **что** в ООО «Рога и копыта» отсутствует потребность в приобретении мотоцикла в 2021 году*. Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным изъяснительным, ставится запятая, но нужен **союз ЧТО**.

**Первая запятая** действительно обособляет деепричастный оборот.

**Правила:** Полный академический справочник под ред. Лопатина.

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

**Примеры (из Нацкорпуса русского языка):**

Что же касается вашей просьбы подарить значки кадетскому классу, то **сообщаем:** они уже отправлены в ваш адрес. По просьбе администрации **сообщаем:** дни посещения в ЦКБ ― четверг, суббота и воскресенье.
На Ваше письмо **сообщаем, что** удовлетворить Вашу просьбу не представляется возможным.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, форум тут не особо активный. Попробую начать своё расследование.

Первая запятая обособляет деепричастный оборот «Рассмотрев Ваше обращение (,)».
Вторая запятая соединяет два простых предложения в составе сложного, последняя запятая обособляет уже причастный оборот.

Верно?

Comment: Вам это "расследование" надо было в вопрос вставить, а не ответ самому себе давать. А так - все верно.  Что касается двоеточия вместо второй запятой (см. Sharon), то, пожалуй, так точнее. Но я не вижк ошибки и в варианте с запятой. Это обсуждаемо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.